# Pandas grouped differences with variable lags

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, series, difference

I have a pandas data frame with three variables.  The first is a grouping variable, the second a within group "scenario" and the third an outcome.  I would like to calculate the within group difference between the null condition, scenario zero, and the other scenarios within the group.  The number of scenarios varies between the different groups.  My data looks like:

`ipdb> aDf
       FieldId  Scenario     TN_load
0            0         0  134.922952
1            0         1  111.787326
2            0         2  104.805951
3            1         0   17.743467
4            1         1   13.411849
5            1         2   13.944552
6            1         3   17.499152
7            1         4   17.640090
8            1         5   14.220673
9            1         6   14.912306
10           1         7   17.233862
11           1         8   13.313953
12           1         9   17.967438
13           1        10   14.051882
14           1        11   16.307317
15           1        12   12.506358
16           1        13   16.266233
17           1        14   12.913150
18           1        15   18.149811
19           1        16   12.337736
20           1        17   12.008868
21           1        18   13.434605
22           2         0  454.857959
23           2         1  414.372215
24           2         2  478.371387
25           2         3  385.973388
26           2         4  487.293966
27           2         5  481.280175
28           2         6  403.285123
29           3         0   30.718375
       ...       ...         ...
29173     4997         3   53.193992
29174     4997         4   45.800968`

I will also have to write functions to get percentage differences etc. but this has me stumped.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the difference with the scenario 0 within groups using `groupby` and `transform` like:

```
df['TN_load_0'] = df['TN_load'].groupby(df['FieldId']).transform(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])

df

    FieldId Scenario    TN_load TN_load_0
0   0              0    134.922952  0.000000
1   0              1    111.787326  -23.135626
2   0              2    104.805951  -30.117001
3   1              0    17.743467   0.000000
4   1              1    13.411849   -4.331618
5   1              2    13.944552   -3.798915
6   1              3    17.499152   -0.244315
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Welcome! Accept the answer if it solved the question :)